# Getting "app.firestore is not a function" when getting data from Firestore in SSR app

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have currently followed a video on youtube on SSR with firebase functions. And that seems to work perfect. Now i am trying to add some additional functionality to my ssr boilerplate app. I want to add Firebase firestore support so i can get data from firebase firestore. I am getting this error `ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: app.firestore is not a function` and this only happens in the function (server). Data is retrieved in the frontend but the SSR part is not working because of the function (server) error. I cant seem to find any solution for this. My code can be viewed here: [Github_Repository](https://github.com/Intellinto/angular-boilerplate/tree/feature/ssr_firebase)

I cant see what i am missing here and hope posting this question will help.

thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @SuhailAKhtar I had to downgrade my firebase package

Answer (score 1):

Use externalDependencies = [
"@firebase/app",
"@firebase/firestore"
] in angular.json file

Below is the code.

```
"server": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/market-web/server",
        "main": "server.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
        "externalDependencies": [
          "@firebase/app",
          "@firebase/firestore"
        ]
      },
  .....
```

Comment: where you had been all these years "MASTER". .... thanks

Comment: After this I encounter ` Cannot read property 'isSupported' of undefined`. Which external dependencies I need to import?